# How to get Elapsed time in Android TimeUnit

Tags: java, android, timeunit

I have a 5 minutes timer. In case i finish 30 seconds its shown 4:30 but i want set 30 seconds .

code to decrease time

```
String timeReminder= String.format(Locale.ENGLISH , "%02d:%02d" , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)) );
            timerText.setText(timeReminder);
```

i want only reminder time.

Comment: Do you mean `remaining` / `remainder`?

Comment: @ack elapsed time

Answer (score 1):

### *java.time*

You can use [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) which is modelled on [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and was introduced with *Java-8* as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html). With *Java-9* some more convenience methods were introduced.

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Duration total = Duration.ofMinutes(5);
        Duration elapsed = Duration.ofSeconds(30);
        Duration remaining = total.minus(elapsed);

        // ###############Java 8###########################
        String timeReminder = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%02d:%02d", remaining.toMinutes(),
                remaining.toSeconds() % 60);
        System.out.println(timeReminder);
        // ################################################

        // ###############Java 9###########################
        timeReminder = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%02d:%02d", remaining.toMinutesPart(), remaining.toSecondsPart());
        System.out.println(timeReminder);
        // ################################################
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
04:30
04:30
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I guess the word you are looking for is elapsed time, however, your logic doesn't seem correct.

So here is the example,

```
Long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
Long estimatedTime = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(10); // For 10 minutes
```

To calculate elapsed time :

```
    Long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
```

To calculate Remaining time :

```
    Long remainingTime = estimatedTime - System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Now you have both times in Millis, You can easily convert and format in Minutes:Second format.